# Feature Engineering: Should I drop features that can be calculated using other features?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering

In feature engineering, should I drop all features that can be calculated using other features?

For example, let us say that we have this dataset:

```
f1    f2    f3        f4     target
1     4     0.25      5      9
3     6     0.5       9      8
5     8     0.625     13     12
2     8     0.25      10     15
```

In this dataset,

> `f3 = f1 / f2`
>
> `f4 = f1 + f2`

- Should we drop f3 and f4?
- Does the decision depend on the size of the dataset?
- Does the decision depend on the algorithm used (Random Forest, Neural Network, etc)?
- Does the decision depend on the machine-learning type: regression, classification, etc?
- Does the decision depend on the formula that links the features? For example, the formula that links `f3` to `f1` and `f2` is simple division.

Can you please also recommend resources to learn more about this topic?

Answer (score 6):

*TL;DR* It depends on the algorithm. In some cases it won't make a difference, in other it will be recommended, yet in other cases it may be harmful.

If you use algorithms that are based on linear combinations of features ($\beta_1 f_1 + \beta_2 f_2 + \dots$), like generalized linear models (including linear regression, logistic regression), or densely connected neural networks, then it doesn't make sense to include variables like $f_4 = f_1 + f_2$, since this is already a build-in feature of the model. Moreover, you would get into problems with [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) (by definition, such feature is linearly dependent on others). Including features such as $f_5 = f_1 f_2$ means using [interaction terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics)) and is commonly used in statistics and $f_3 = f_1 / f_2$ is just an [interaction in disguise](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129981/interactions-using-ratio-of-variables/129987#129987).

On another hand, with algorithms like random forest you could [use exactly the same variable multiple times](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/377033/collinearity-of-features-and-random-forest/377047#377047) and it wouldn't matter, since what decision trees do is they look at one variable at a time to make a split. Adding such features when using random forest may make sense and [simplify the task for the algorithm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350220/utility-of-feature-engineering-why-create-new-features-based-on-existing-featu/350238#350238).